# How to apply parallax effect to UITableView header that contains horizontal UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I created screen that contains `UITableView`. The tableView header contains horizontal `UICollectionView` and that collectionView contains cells with imageView and some other view.

The question is how to apply parallax effect to all view in the tableView header?

Comment: When you say parallax, do you mean that you want rectangles to be distorted into keystone shapes?

Comment: Did you find a good solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Implement the `UIScrollViewDelegate` method `scrollViewDidScroll`. There you can examine the `contentOffset` of the table view and modify the collection view height (via the `constant` of a `NSLayoutConstraint`) and its `contentOffset`.

Comment: Would you have to change the tableview header height too, as changing just the collection view could leave a white space underneath??

Comment: No, I would just keep the distance between table and collection view constant.

Comment: The scrolling action feels most natural if you set the `contentOffset` of the table view to zero as long as the height of the view above is greater than zero.